# Matlab: extract submatrix with selecting some values from the last line

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

```
      20     4     4    74    20    20  74  85 85 85
 A =  36     1     1    11    36    36  11  66 66 66 
      77     1     1    15    77    77  15  11 11 11
      3      4     2     6     7     8  10  10 15 17
```

how from the matrix `A`, I can extract the submatrix whose `fourth line` (end line) contains only the values ​​`[3 6 10]`?

for a single value, I do:

```
B=A(:,A(4,:)==10)
```

but I do not know how to do this for several values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html)** -

```
search_array = [3 6 10]
subA = A(:,ismember(A(end,:),search_array))
```

Or **[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** -

```
subA = A(:,any(bsxfun(@eq,A(end,:),search_array(:)),1))
```